# Connection refused socket programming in C AF_UNIX

Tags: c, sockets, connection, errno

Hi i'm trying to make a simple program that forks and then should act like client/server. Here is my code:

```
int main (){
int sfd,fdc;
struct sockaddr_un sa;
strncpy(sa.sun_path,SOCKNAME,UNIX_PATH_MAX);
sa.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
char buf[N+1];

if (fork() != 0){
    sfd = socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    bind (sfd, (struct sockaddr *) &sa ,sizeof(sa));
    listen(sfd, SOMAXCONN);
    fdc= accept(sfd,NULL,0);
    read(fdc,buf,N);
    printf("Server got: %s\n",buf);
    write(fdc,"bye!",5);
    close(fdc);
    close(sfd);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
else {
    sfd = socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    while(connect(sfd, (struct sockaddr *)&sa,sizeof(sa)) == -1){
        if (errno == ENOENT){
            printf("Aspetto 1 sec\n");
            sleep(1);
        }
        else {perror(NULL); exit(EXIT_FAILURE) ;}   
    }
    write(sfd,"Hallo!",7);
    read(sfd,buf,N);
    printf("Client got: %s\n",buf);
    close(sfd);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

I don't understand why this fail when i try to connect the client to server. I got this error: Connection Refused.
I can't really find where the problem is, thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like your first problem might be a race condition. Is there any reason to think that the client is not trying to connect before the server is listening?

Comment: i think i've figured out which is the problem:i create a socket when the program runs but then i dont eliminate it, so i have a file called mysock and will not make my program runs.
If i manually delete it the code will run perfectly...once...how can i resolve that now ?

Answer (score 0):

First, regarding *simple program that forks and then should act like client/server*:  Having a client *and* server in the same logical block is not a good idea. although it can be written to be syntactically correct (i.e. it will compile and build), I do not see how it will ever be practical.

There are many tutorial examples, using Posix C to create separate server and client apps.  ***[Here is one](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm)***.  ***[Here is another](http://www.binarytides.com/socket-programming-c-linux-tutorial/)***, and ***[a third](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/linux-programming/121131-posix-sockets-c.html)***.

One general suggestion, when using a family of functions that have prerequisites  (such as a handle for a socket, or for a previous successful call of another function), you should always use the return value.  For example, in the following lines of your example code:

```
if (fork() != 0){
    sfd = socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    bind (sfd, (struct sockaddr *) &sa ,sizeof(sa));
    listen(sfd, SOMAXCONN);
    fdc= accept(sfd,NULL,0);
```

the only line you choose to verify is the result of fork (that is good).  But you should also check the results of each of the others, using the results as a prerequisite of continuing to the next step.

At the very least something like this:

```
if (fork() != 0)
{
    sfd = socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sfd < 0)
    {
        //notify user
        return -1;
    }
    ret = bind (sfd, (struct sockaddr *) &sa ,sizeof(sa));
    if(ret < 0)
    {
        //check value of errno, and notify user
        return -1;
    }
    ret = listen(sfd, SOMAXCONN);
    if(ret < 0)
    {
        //check value of errno, and notify user
        return -1;
    }
    new_s= accept(sfd,NULL,0); 
    if(new_s < 0)
    {
        //check value of errno, and notify user
        return -1;
    }
    // continue...
```

Comment: thanks for your good advice, i didnt put controls because i posted it there and could be a little bit much difficult to read the code, so i'd rather dont check every command.
I found out how to resolve my problem simple using: unlink().